# performing multiple separate sums with separate filters on a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sum

I have a table with an amount column a reference field and an id column. What I need to do is sum the amount based on different combinations of ID's for each reference. There are nine different combinations in total that I then need to insert into a separate table.

The best way I've found to do this is to use a cursor and do each SUM separately, assign the amount to a variable and update the table for each reference and for each combination.

Hope that makes sense!

What I was hoping to find out is - is there a better way to do it?

thanks.

Comment: Any time that you are using a cursor in SQL Server, it is 99.99% likely that there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (Id = 9) THEN Val ELSE 0 END) ConditionalSum
  From dbo.Table
```

You can have many of those SUMs with different conditions in one query.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a table called something like `combos` with the following columns:

- Name of combination
- reference id in combination

(and perhaps other useful columns like an id and creation time, but that is not important here).

Insert your combinations into this table, something like:

```
First10     1
First10     2
...
First10     10
MyFavorite  42
```

Whatever the pairs are.

Then you can do what you want with a single query:

```
select c.comboName, sum(val) as ConditionalSum
from t join
     combos c
     on t.referenceId = c.referenceId
group by c.comboName
```